# ckeditor not loading in IE when used in two applications

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ckeditor

I have a central location where ckeditor in stored.

Header web application uses ckeditor successfully in IE, Firefox and Chrome.

Header is loaded all the time for all web applications in the domain.

Web application X needs ckeditor. Web application waits(using timeouts) for the CKEDITOR object to be available and then uses it.

This works in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE. What am I missing here?

The timeouts in IE keep on going but the CKEDITOR object is never available.

Code:

```
namespace Models
{
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public class EmailModel
    {
        public int EmailID { get; set; }
        public string FromAddress { get; set; }
        public string ToAddresses { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Subject is required.")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Subject cannot be greater than 50 characters.")]
        public string Subject { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Body is required.")]
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Html:

```
@model Models.EmailModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Email Template Details";
}

<h2>Email Template Details</h2>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/EmailDetails.js?version=06.07.2016_1156"></script>

<div>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FromAddress)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FromAddress)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Subject)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Subject)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Body)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Body)
            <textarea id="editorBodyDetails" name="editorBodyDetails" style="display:none"></textarea>
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.EmailID }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Email Templates", "Index")
</p>
```

Script:

```
var countCKEDITORAttemps = 0;

$(function () {

    initializeCKEDITOROnceLoaded(countCKEDITORAttemps);

});

function initializeCKEDITOROnceLoaded(countCKEDITORAttemps) {
    var interval = 1000; // ms
    if (countCKEDITORAttemps < 100) {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            if (typeof(CKEDITOR) !== 'undefined') {
                setupCKEditor("editorBodyEdit");
            } else {
                countCKEDITORAttemps = countCKEDITORAttemps + 1;
                console.log("Loading CKEDITOR:" + countCKEDITORAttemps * 1000 + "milliseconds");
                window.setTimeout(initializeCKEDITOROnceLoaded(countCKEDITORAttemps), interval);
            }
        }, interval);
    }
}

function setupCKEditor(id) {
    CKEDITOR.replace(id, { height: 200, });
    CKEDITOR.instances[id].setData($("#Body").val());
}
```

NOTE: I am not including ckeditor in Web application X

The line at which ckeditor loading in IE seems to have a problem is here:

```
var b=d[c].src.match(a);
```

The "src" is not available. Could it be the anticache setting that is causing problems in IE loading?

Error message during load:

"Error: Invalid argument.\n   at Anonymous function ([http://domain.com/includes/ckeditor/ckeditor.js?anti-cache=09Jun2016&*=1468730100637:5:431*](http://domain.com/includes/ckeditor/ckeditor.js?anti-cache=09Jun2016&_=1468730100637:5:431))\n   at Anonymous function ([http://domain.com/includes/ckeditor/ckeditor.js?anti-cache=09Jun2016&=1468730100637:5:153](http://domain.com/includes/ckeditor/ckeditor.js?anti-cache=09Jun2016&_=1468730100637:5:153))\n   at Anonymous function ([http://domain.com/includes/ckeditor/ckeditor.js?anti-cache=09Jun2016&*=1468730100637:5:78*](http://domain.com/includes/ckeditor/ckeditor.js?anti-cache=09Jun2016&_=1468730100637:5:78))\n   at Global code ([http://domain.com/includes/ckeditor/ckeditor.js?anti-cache=09Jun2016&=1468730100637:5:2](http://domain.com/includes/ckeditor/ckeditor.js?anti-cache=09Jun2016&_=1468730100637:5:2))"

Comment: Please provide the HTML you are working with and if possible a working fiddle that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by checking all the scripts that were being loaded in my application. One of the scripts loading had a problem and was hindering the loading of ckeditor on IE.

Answer (score -1):

You can also fix this by changing the orders of your scripts in the application.